# How to write Mocha test case for js

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, push-notification, mocha.js

I have a js file, use for push notification. And a file mocha test case. But not working.
Help me please!.

server.js

```
export.PushApnIOS = function(notification, tokenUser, listTokenUserDelete){
    // push.set("title" : "test");
    // set data of push
push.send().then(function(pushS) {
        // OK
        // show log
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // show log
        // if err.code = 1004E or 1005E, listTokenUserDelete += tokenUser 
    });
}); 
}
```

Mocha testcase file
mochaTest.js

```
    describe('export PushApnIOS', function() {
      it('push OK', function() {
          push.send().then(function(pushS){
              assert.equal(pushS, push);
          });
      });
      
      it('Error', function() {
          push.send().catch(function(err){
              assert.equal(err.code,"1004E");
              assert.equal(err.code,"1005E");
          });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Where does `push.send()` come from?